# input a floating point number an output it back to the screen in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, input, output

i've been working on this assignment, and cant get past one of the first parts, which should be simple.  Ive been over it with my professor, but he can't figure it out either...I was hoping for some help here.  I just want to input a number, push it into st0, then pop and store it into total_mean.  For testing purposes, ive commented out the code in the beginning.

```
extern printf
extern scanf

segment .data
    prompt_name db "Please enter you name: ", 0
    input_name db "%s %s",0
    ready db "Please have your numberic data ready",10,0
    get_num db "Enter a floating number: ",0
    stringdata db "%s",0

    namedata db "%s ",0
    display_name db "%s",10,0
    floatdata db "%Lf",0
    ask db "Are there more numbers (Y or N)? ", 0

    mean db "The mean of these %d values is %Lf",10,0
    largest db "the largest value is %Lf",10,0
    smallest db "the smallest value is %Lf",10,0

    more db "Do you have more data to analyze (Y or N)? ",0

    bye db "Thank you %s. I hope you enjoyed this program.",10,0


segment .bss
    user_float: resq 1
    large: resq 1
    small: resq 1
    total_mean: resq 2
    first_name: resb 32
    last_name: resq 32

segment .text

    global start_loop

start_loop:

;   mov rax,0
;   mov rdi, stringdata
;   mov rsi, prompt_name
;   call printf
;
;   mov qword rax, 0
;   mov rdi, input_name
;   mov rsi, first_name
;   mov rdx, last_name
;   call scanf
;
;   mov rax, 0
;   mov rdi, namedata
;   mov rsi, first_name
;   call printf
;
;   mov rax, 0
;   mov rdi, display_name
;   mov rsi, last_name
;   call printf
;
;   mov rax, 0
;   mov rdi, stringdata
;   mov rsi, ready
;   call printf
;
;   mov rax, 0
;   mov rdi, stringdata
;   mov rsi, get_num
;   call printf

    mov qword rax, 0
    push qword 0
    push qword 0
    mov rdi, floatdata
    mov rsi, rsp
    call scanf

    push qword 0
    push qword 0

    fld tword [rsp]
    fmul

    fstp tword [total_mean]

    mov qword rax, 0
    mov qword rax,0
    mov rdi, floatdata
    mov rsi, total_mean
    call printf

    pop rax
    pop rax
    pop rax
    pop rax

ret
```

Its just the bottom half where im trying to get an input from the keyboard that im having a problem with.  When i input a number, such as 12.0, and display it, it displays 0.00000.  Can anyone help me find a solution to this please?

Comment: The easiest way to solve these sorts of problems is to write the program in C and ask the compiler for the asm. That's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In x86-64 you pass `double` arguments in `XMM` registers, not in the 80387 fpu stack. As you're using SystemV ABI here (it's visible by `printf` and `scanf` calls), just put the first `double` argument to `XMM0`, the second (if any) to `XMM1` and so on (up to `XMM7`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i dont really understand, partly because we've never learned about the XMM register. So am i supposed to change FLD TWORD [total_mean]?  any which way i change it fails to compile.  How else do load it into XMM0?